WooCommerce: Allow Subscription renewal for user who is not logged in
Stuck on a problem trying to allow for a manual subscription renewal for a failed order (and on-hold subscription) while the user is not logged in.
When the payment retry fails 5 times, it leave old subscribers On-hold.
They are able to be sent a link to renew their subscription, but they are required to log in first.
Sub renewal link: {YOURSITE}.com/checkout/order-pay/{ORDER_ID}/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order\_{ORDER_KEY}&subscription_renewal=true
I have tried Pay without need to login WooCommerce answer code from @Stirling. 
However, the code seemly gets passed the login requirement, adds the correct order details to the cart... Great! 
But when the order is processed, the order isn't then linked to the subscription. The existing subscription isn't renewed, and the new order is an "orphaned" subscription order.
UPDATE: The above code, successfully logs the user in on first load. IF you load the same renewal link again, you get a success message on checkout "Complete checkout to renew your subscription." and the re-subscribe works if processed
It's as if the sub code first requires the user to be logged in before the check happens... Which is also consistant with Woo Subscription code which actions this here https://github.com/Automattic/woocommerce-subscriptions-core/blob/trunk/includes/class-wcs-cart-renewal.php
Can anyone assist?
Looks possible from the source code https://github.com/Automattic/woocommerce-subscriptions-core/blob/trunk/includes/class-wcs-cart-renewal.php
I also already have code that works for the initial order stage which allows a user to process an order without logging in, works for both single payment orders and subscription orders
This code + Woo settings will

Allow user to process order without logging in

Create an account for user if they don't have an account

Will create an account if doesn't exist

Will add paid order to existing account, even if user not logged in.


add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 10, 1);
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data( $data) {
    // Exit function if user is logged in to let checkout process as normal
    if ( is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $data;
    }
    /* If we have a user, we need to set the WP current user so that WooCommerce has a user and doesn't think it needs
    to create another one for that user's email. If an existing user is not found, then create a new one. */
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout()) {
        // Make sure not logged in and are on checkout page.
        $user = get_user_by('email', $data['billing_email']);
        
        if ( !empty($user->ID) ) {
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            $data['createaccount'] = 0; // Unset flag to create a new user.
        }
        else {
            $data['createaccount'] = 1; // Set the flag to create a new user.
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

